# Fantasy book where magic can pull objects from other dimensions

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Recently I was going back to all those books I read and loved when I was younger ... much younger than now :)

I fondly remember a fantasy series of books but cannot remember character names, titles or even the author.

Here is what I remember and I hope somebody can help me rediscover the books author and titles.

- Read it around 1995 but I think it wasn't new even then because I got it from a public library.
- It was a translation into german from an english original.
- The main protagonist is a young man (perhaps lost his parents early on? Cannot remember)
- He is magically adept but has no concept what it is he does (and no education)
- He is picked up and trained by an older mage
- Most importantly I remember how magic works in the books: You pull objects from other dimensions into your own.
- I remember that it is mentioned that weather manipulation is of limits (I think the main character tries it anyways, young adults :)
- I think I remember a battle between mages. Monsters being summoned on both sides of a fields (I've been playing MTG (created 1993) at that time so that sounded familiar)
- ~3 books in the series I think at that time (ca. 1995)
- Target age I would say was for "young adults"

Perhaps you can help me summon that knowledge back from the dimension where I'm still younger :)

UPDATE:
All of you are so magnificant! Seriously many many thanks.
It IS the Belgariad and Mallorean series by David Eddings as @sueelleker pointed out in the comments.

I thanks you very much and now I'm off to buying those for myself.

This will be a happy christmas :)

Comment: A bit similar to the "The Chronicles of Amber" by Roger Zelazny, just take a look (not much about beast summoning, just ones, and "young mage" Merlin knows very well about his training and concept). Summoning a bottle of beer - yes, everyday )

Comment: Some parts sound like the Belgariad and Mallorean series by David Eddings. Near the start of the Mallorean the protagonist (Belgarion) summons a storm to stop a battle and is told off for it. Later they meet demon summoners, and summon their own demons to fight them.

Answer (score 1):

As per the querent's edit of their question, this is David Eddings's *Belgariad* and *Mallorean* book.

Garion starts as an orphaned boy on Faldor's farm in Sendaria. He is from a magical bloodline (and heir to the throne of Riva). His "Aunt Pol" and "Grandfather" Belgarath (actually distant ancestors) do eventually tutor him in sorcery in preparation to fight Torak to fulfill the Prophecy. There are occasional cases of pulling objects into being, but more often it's a mix of telekinesis, evocation, and transmutation. Demons are summoned a handful of times in the books, but it's dangerous and deals with dark forces.

The weather manipulation primarily comes up in the *Mallorean*, where Garion (by then Belgarion) gets dressed down by Belgarath for invoking a storm without understanding how that will affect the weather elsewhere.